# The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format - swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, url, alamofire

I'm having trouble reading JSON from URL request

My JSON

```
{"id" : "screens" ,"title" : "Skærmbilleder" ,"imagepath" : "https://www.spiritbooks.dk/service/menu/screens.png"},{"id" : "presale" ,"title" : "Presale" ,"imagepath" : "https://www.spiritbooks.dk/service/menu/presale.png"},{"id" : "discount" ,"title" : "Rabatkoder" ,"imagepath" : "https://www.spiritbooks.dk/service/menu/discount.png"},{"id" : "contact" ,"title" : "Kontakt" ,"imagepath" : "https://www.spiritbooks.dk/service/menu/contact.png"},{"id" : "about" ,"title" : "Om hjertechakra appen" ,"imagepath" : "https://www.spiritbooks.dk/service/menu/about.png"},
```

My code

```
        AF.request("myUrl").responseJSON { response in
            if let result = response.data {
                do {
                    // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
                        
                        for categoryData in json{
                            var category = Category()
                            
                            if let id = categoryData["id"] as? String{
                                category.id = id
                            }
                            
                            if let title = categoryData["title"] as? String{
                                category.title = title
                            }
                            if let imagepath = categoryData["imagepath"] as? String{
                                category.imagepath = imagepath
                            }
                            
                            self.categories.append(category)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I get the error code " Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Comment: `print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")` => `print("Failed to load: \(error) with response: \(String(data: result, encoding: .utf8))")` and give us that output

Comment: ... and delete `let error as NSError`

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is not legal. Paste it into [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com) and it'll show you the error. Your data seems to mean to be a JSON Array, but it isn't wrapped in `[...]`.